# How to find from where sbt is picking repositories file information

Tags: sbt

I am having issues to make sbt to pick dependencies.

I want to know from where sbt is reading the repositories information. Means which file it is reading.

Can we get the file name and location.

I tried to see project/repositories

and .sbt/repositores

they are not having content which sbt is showing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`show resolvers` and `show externalResolvers` will show all of the Maven and/or Ivy repositories that your dependencies can be pulled from.

`show fullClasspath` will show the full pathnames of all of the JARs on your classpath.